# Serverless WebSockets - No method found matching route @connections/* for http method POST

Tags: javascript, websocket, serverless

I'm using Serverless Framework to host my WebSocket, which has the typical $connect, $disconnect, $default, etc methods that updates my connections db:

```
case '$connect':
  await dynamoDb.put({
    TableName: process.env.CONNECTIONS_TABLE,
    Item: {
      connectionId,
      // Expire the connection an hour later. This is optional, but recommended.
      // You will have to decide how often to time out and/or refresh the ttl.
      ttl: parseInt((Date.now() / 1000) + 3600)
    }
  }).promise();
```

My WebSocket setup is:

```
WebSocket URL: wss://1111111111.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/
Connection URL: https://1111111111.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/@connections
```

My HTTP setup is:

```
Invoke API at: https://222222222.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev/
```

[image]

I have a broadcast function which I am using to send data to the connections, which I am invoking with:

```
sls invoke --function broadcast --data '{ \"body\": \"Hello from server\" }'
```

The source sends a message to each connection, as provided in the params of the request:

```
async function sendMessage(connectionId, body) {
  try {
    await apig.postToConnection({
      ConnectionId: connectionId,
      Data: body
    }).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore if connection no longer exists
    if(err.statusCode !== 400 && err.statusCode !== 410) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}

async function getAllConnections(ExclusiveStartKey) {
  const { Items, LastEvaluatedKey } = await dynamoDb.scan({
    TableName: process.env.CONNECTIONS_TABLE,
    AttributesToGet: [ 'connectionId' ],
    ExclusiveStartKey
  }).promise();

  const connections = Items.map(({ connectionId }) => connectionId);
  if(LastEvaluatedKey) {
    connections.push(...await getAllConnections(LastEvaluatedKey));
  }
  return connections;
}

module.exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  const { body } = event;
  const connections = await getAllConnections();

  await Promise.all(
    connections.map(connectionId => sendMessage(connectionId, body))
  );
}
```

A connection can be established (I can connect to the WebSocket), however when I try to invoke this function I am receiving the error:

> No method found matching route @connections/ZE4SDfSJSwMCJ4g%3D for http method POST.

The `ZE4SDfSJSwMCJ4g` is my connectionId, which exists in my database. I am unsure if this routing issue has to do with my HTTP API and my WebSocket API being pointed at different API Gateway URL?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the endpoint in your API Gateway management configuration is the same as your ws endpoint.

```
const agma = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
  apiVersion: AGMA_VERSION,
  endpoint: WS_ENDPOINT // 1111111111.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev
})
```

Comment: This! I blindly copied and pasted code that generates the endpoint from a lambda that belongs to my WS API to a new lambda that's part of my REST API

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue with websockets and google cloud functions. I think it's because the web socket server is put to sleep and doesn't actively listen because it's serverless.

Functions are configured to wake up on http requests (ports 80/443) and go back to sleep, so they need to be specially configured to wake up to requests on web socket port.

This seems possible using a serverless websockets plugin  https://github.com/serverless/serverless-websockets-plugin  there is a how to article at https://www.serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-websockets-example

Comment: The plugin is deprecated, it now exists in the current version of Serverless Framework. I don't think this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, when I started using a custom domain on AWS. Custom domains doesnt require stage to be added in the end. Remove the stage from the url it would work fine.

Custom domain as in, I was using `https://mywebsite.com`, and when we append the stage, it was like `https://mywebsite.com/dev`.  Then I got the above error. removing the stage fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just coding like this will fix,remove "@connections":
client = boto3.client('apigatewaymanagementapi',endpoint_url="https://aaaaaaaa.execute-api.
us-west-2.amazonaws.com/production")
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print(event)###
response = client.post_to_connection(
Data= 'response from lambda',
ConnectionId='PNMw2elEPHcCEmw='
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).